# How to print array data without displaying any if else statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have a following sample code from my lecture note. in my code if you try to print one directly, you get an output that does not match what I want. How to print a car list that I just select it. Without displaying any other lines. But if the input is less than 1 and over 3 then it displays the wrong message

```
  package scanner1;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Scanner1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  int carSelect;
  int [] noNumb = {1,2,3};
  String [] carList = {"Lexus","Bugati","McLaren"};

  System.out.println("================ Car List ================");
    for (int i = 0; i < noNumb.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(noNumb [i]+". "+carList[i]);
    }     
     System.out.println(" ");
     System.out.print("Choose your car : ");
     carSelect = scan.nextInt ();
     loop:
     for (int i=0; i<noNumb.length; i++){
     if(carSelect == noNumb [i]){
         System.out.println("Great you choose " +carList[i]);
         break;
    }else if (carSelect <= noNumb[i]){
         System.out.println("Your input is less than 1 ");  
        break;
    } else {
         System.out.println("Wrong input ");

    }
    }
} }
```

Output:

```
 ================ Car List ================
 1. Lexus
 2. Bugati
 3. McLaren

 Choose your car : 3
 Wrong input 
 Wrong input 
 Great you choose McLaren
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Why do you have a for loop? What's the point?

Comment: I think you're looking for a while loop to check valid input

Comment: By the way, your logic isn't exactly checking "Your input is less than 1"

Comment: @AndrewLi My lecturer assigned me to work on this case with a for loop, I also don't know why. I think, the loop is used to retrieve the index array :)

Comment: @cricket_007 I have not tried it yet, but thanks for your advice :)

Comment: You don't need an "index array". `System.out.println((i+1)+". "+carList[i]);` will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
if (carSelect < 1){
     System.out.println("Your input is less than 1 ");  
} else if (carSelect > 3) {
     System.out.println("Wrong input ");
} else {   
   //valid input, let us check the car selected
   System.out.println("Great you choose " +carList[carSelect]);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is going for a reprompt for an invalid input, thus the (invalid) for loop.

Comment: Even I dont understand his intention for that loop. His question and that code is not in sync.